# Rest kit VS ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: restkit

I am using "RestKit 0.20.3` in my project,

due to some crucial reasons I am going to convert all my API calls to Ret kit,

please can any one tell me how can I make a same call like below with rest kit
I am sending my `ASIHHTP` code
please can any one migrate it to Rest kit, I unable to find the way

```
NSDictionary *dictionary=....;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@auth/login",KBASEURL]];


ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];


[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];


[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];


[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];


 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDictionary options:kNilOptions error:nil];

[request setPostBody:(NSMutableData *)jsonData];

[request setContentLength:[jsonData length]];
```

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is more similar to AFNetworking. What is yor source data? What have you tried? What research have you done on mapping and posting with RestKit?

Comment: Everything is done, my problem is unable to set content type and dataI did not work on AFNetworking before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RKObjectManager *manager =  [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://172.22.221.117/api/v1.0/"]];

 NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"abc.com",@"email",@"password",@"password", nil];

[manager postObject:nil
               path:@"auth/login"
         parameters:dictionary
            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {


            }
            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                if(operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode==200){
                    //do your processing
                }
            }];
```

Comment: I know this is not standard way of doing. I should make this code compatible to my previous code